# how to break {{#each}} in emberjs handlebars

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I want to know how to `break` or `continue` `{{#each}} loop` in emberjs handlebars.

```
 <ul>
   {{#each people}}
     //if name == 'xyz' i want to break the loop
     // else list the name
     <li>{{name}}</li>
   {{/each}}
 </ul>
```

I know how to use conditions, like below

```
   {{#if (eq name "xyz")}}
        bye
    {{else}}
        {{name}}
    {{/if}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `break` or `continue` in emberjs handlebars for `each` block. so I would encourage you to modify the `people` array through computed property.

```
peopleLimited:Ember.comptued('people.[]',function(){
 let result = [];
 //implement your logic here to cut down people array.
 return result;
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I have one more question....is it possible to call function in if condition ? like {{#if functionName param1 param2}}ok{{else}}not ook{{/if}} and function will be in my component.js ?

Comment: You can't call function available in component.js file, but you can write helper to implement your logic. and you can call it like this `{{#if (helper-name param1 param2)}}ok{{else}}not ook{{/if}}`